# Compute the supremum over all partitions of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f \in C^1[0,1]$. For a partition 
$$(P):0=x_0 <x_1<x_2<...<x_n=1$$

define $$S(P)= \sum _{i=1}^{n} \vert f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) \vert .$$

> Compute the supremum of $S(P)$ taken over all possible partitions $P$.

Intermediate value theorem gives that $S(P)< \infty$, but how to compute this?

Comment: When does the sum accumulate the most "stuff"? You'll want a partition that puts an $x_i$ at each point where $f$ attains a local maximum or minimum, so that $S(P)$ accumulates all "motion" that happens in $f$. Then $$\sup(S(P)) = \int_{0}^{1}\lvert f'(t) \rvert \, dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that the supremum given in the problem is defined as the [Total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) of the function $f$. By Theorem 1 from the Wikipedia link, the total variation of a $C^1$ function on the interval $[a,b]$  is nothing else than
$$\int_a^b |f'(x)|dx.$$

By Lagrange's theorem $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y| \cdot |f'(\zeta)|$ for some $\zeta\in (y,x)$ whenever $y<x.$ Therefore, if you have any partition $\mathcal P$, then 
$$\sum_{\mathcal P}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=\sum_{\mathcal P}|f'(\zeta_i)||x_{i}-x_{i-1}|$$ for some $\zeta_i\in (x_{i-1},x_i)$. Since $f\in C^1[0,1]$, then $f'$ and $|f'|$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ so that the supremum in your question is just the Riemannian integral of $|f'|$ on the interval $[0,1].$ This finishes the proof.

Comment: How do we know that $S(P)\leq \int^b_a |f'(x)| dx $ ?

Comment: Suprema over $\mathcal P$ on both sides of the equality above are the same. The left hand side is your supremum, and the right hand side supremum is the Riemannian integral of $|f'|$ by basic theorem from calculus. This supremum does not depend on partitions and on the choice of $\zeta_i$ by theorem when  the length of the longest interval in the partition tends to zero. To understand this more thoroughly go again through the construction of Riemannian integral with Riemannian and Darboux sums.